# Vanilla JS Single Sign-On attempt with MSAL.js leading to pop-up window showing a copy of the same page

Tags: javascript, popup, single-sign-on, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I've copied the example app at this repository to try to implement single sign-on: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-v2. I've changed the config values match those of the Azure configuration. I'm using the public version of the authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[APP VALUE HERE]" in this configuration as well.

For additional background - I had previously not had the redirectURL correctly matching, and the popup window from running the example showed my user account name before failing with an error. From this I take it to mean that the sign-on itself was successful in recognizing me, and that any problems are happening after that point.

The problem I'm running into now is that the SSO popup just loads an exact copy of the page that I used to launch the request in the first place - exact same display and everything. My logging shows that the request to **myMSALObj.loginPopup({scopes: ["User.Read"]})** never completes, it simply hangs until I close the popup window, at which point it fails into the catch block for that request with the following error: "*BrowserAuthError: user_cancelled: User cancelled the flow.*"

So it seems like the process is waiting for some step that never occurs, presumably coming as part of the call within the popup window. Has anyone else encountered this issue before? Does anyone have any recommendation for how to fix it or how to dig deeper into what's occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens if the page you use as your redirectUri is either clearing the url hash on load or redirecting to another page on load. We usually recommend people use a blank page that doesn't implement any logic as their redirectUri to avoid issues like this. If that's not possible try to see what might be causing the server response to be removed from the popup.

Comment: When you say to use a blank page with no logic, what do you mean? Like literally just a plain html document? I think I'm not understanding what the purpose of the redirectURI is, exactly, especially because this example uses the "popup" option.

Comment: It looks like the URL hash is being preserved, I see #code=... at the end, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: If I have a page with just a line of text for the redirectURI, I now see that in the popup, but run into the same error. It might also be worth mentioning that I'm running the client as a test from my local dev machine, so the site (and redirectURI) are for localhost.

Comment: Are the site and redirectUri running on the same localhost port? When the popup is returned to your redirectUri the main window will strip off the params and close the popup. If the params are still in the url of the popup and it's not being closed that means either the main window stopped monitoring the popup (unlikely given you get the user_cancelled error) or the popup is not on the same domain. I recommend opening an [issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues) on Github with a repro where you'll get more traction than on StackOverflow.

Comment: Ah, when the main window was being launched, it was running as 127.etc and then the popup was opening as localhost (ports matching). If I reload the main page as localhost, then the popup opens and closes with a different error. So I think that means I got a step closer to a solution.

Comment: Now it's: 
FetchClient.ts:58 POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<MY APP ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token 401 (Unauthorized)

and then says that "The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'."

Comment: This means either your redirectUri is not registered in the portal as type "SPA" or you have multiple localhost uris registered as different types. Make sure you only register 1 localhost uri and it is of type "SPA"